# MongoTimeoutException: No Server Match - MongoDB Atlas

Tags: java, database, mongodb, timeout, mongodb-atlas

For a few days now, I can't connect to any of my MongoDB Databases that are hosted by Altas. I'm always getting a MongoTimeoutException

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@3691e69a. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=statify-shard-00-02.st9vh.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request}}, {address=statify-shard-00-00.st9vh.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request}}, {address=statify-shard-00-01.st9vh.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request}}]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:407)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:118)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.selectServer(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:52)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:137)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:95)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:266)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:170)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
at de.visionvenue.statify.main.Main.lambda$3(Main.java:235)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Line 233-235 in Main

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = MongoDBHandler.getDatabase().getCollection("statistics");
FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find();
Iterator<Document> it = iterDoc.iterator();
```

Here is the class where I connect to the Database

```
public class MongoDBHandler {

static MongoDatabase db;

public static void connect() {

    try {

        ConnectionString connString = new ConnectionString(
                "mongodb+srv://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@statify.st9vh.mongodb.net/[DATABASE]?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(connString)
                .retryWrites(true).build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Database");
        System.out.println("Connected to database");

        db = database;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String error = ex.toString() + "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
            error = error + ex.getStackTrace()[i].toString() + "\n";
        }
        ReportManager.createInstantReport("MongoDB Connection", error);
    }
}

public static MongoDatabase getDatabase() {
    return db;
    }
}
```

I replaced the user, password and database for this post.

I already checked everything twice. The IP is whitelisted, the connection server is the same, username and password are correct. This code worked fine, but suddenly broke. I haven't changed anything releated to the Database that could cause this issue.

Comment: Yes I did. I just censored it here

Comment: Which IP did you whitelisted?

Comment: I whitelisted my local IP. The Application is running on my PC. I already tryied allowing access from everywhere, but that haven't helped too

Comment: Please whitelist 0.0.0.0 ip

Comment: If you whitelisted 0.0.0.0 IP, then it will give access to all IP addresses.

Comment: Like i said, I tried this already but that didn't helped. I just tried it again and same error

Comment: Did you checked the connection with any mongo client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just contacted the MongoDB Support. They told me that this is a current bug in TLS 1.3. I changed the Java Version to 8 and it worked

The official Bug Report can be found here:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236039