# Is it so that MongoDB doesnot work with JDA (Java Discord Api)?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, discord, discord-jda

I tried to connect my java Discord bot to MongoDB, but it never got connected to mongo Atlas and showed a Timeout 30000ms error. It only got connected to the local database that I set up using mongod command.

When I tried to connect another java program (a simple java program with just 5-6 lines of code to connect java to mongodb) to MongoDB using the same driver and same link, it got connected without any error.
I am sure that everything else like dependencies etc was kept the same.

So is it true that Mongo Atlas does not allow connection to Java Discord Api (JDA) based applications or was it because JDA uses an asynchronous way to run listener adapters?
Or was it because JDA

Comment: That seems very unlikely, why would one forbid you from using the other? And how? Most likely there was some mistake in the bot that caused the timeout, which you did not make in the simple program.

Comment: @Clashsoft but if there was a problem with my bot, then why was it working correctly on the local database?

Comment: I use the JDA and MongoDB and it works fine

Comment: Can you tell us what Java Version you are using?

Comment: @Redi I am using java 8 with JDK 15

Comment: I was having the same issue with JDK 11 and there was a Bug that should be already fixed in JDK 15, but you could try to switch to JDK 8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322521/mongotimeoutexception-no-server-match-mongodb-atlas